# Cucumber-JVM Step definitions

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

After creating my feature file in eclipse, i run it as a Cucumber feature. i use the step definition the console gives me to create the first base of the test file

```
@Given("^the input is <(\\d+)> <(\\d+)>$")
```

these should be outputted by the console however currently it is showing the feature without the step definitions.

```
Feature: this is a test
  this test is to test if this test works right

  Scenario: test runs # src/test/resources/Test.feature:4
    Given: i have a test
    When: i run the test
    Then: i have a working test


0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0,000s
```

this feature is just to check if cucumber is working properly.

the runner:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false,
        format = "pretty",
        features = "src/test/resources/"
        )
public class RunCukes {
}
```

what can be the cause of the console not showing all the info?

TL:DR console does not show the step regex for missing steps

EDIT: added feature file

```
Feature: this is a test
  this test is to test if this test works right

  Scenario: test runs
    Given: i have a test
    When: i run the test
    Then: i have a working test
```

Comment: Post your feature file as well please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the feature file. Using **:** after **Given**, **When** and **Then** is the problem. I was able to reproduce your issue with your feature file. But when I removed the **:** and ran the feature file, with the same Runner options provided above, I got the regex to implement missing step definitions.

P.S I am using IntelliJ, but don't think it would make a difference.

```
  Feature: this is a test
  this test is to test if this test works right

  Scenario: test runs # src/test/resources/Test.feature:4
    Given i have a test
    When i run the test
    Then i have a working test
```

Below is what I got:

```
Testing started at 19:12 ...

Undefined step: Given  i have a test

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
3 Steps (3 undefined)
0m0.000s

Undefined step: When  i run the test

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
@Given("^i have a test$")

public void i_have_a_test() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^i run the test$")
public void i_run_the_test() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^i have a working test$")
public void i_have_a_working_test() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}


Undefined step: Then  i have a working test

1 scenario (0 passed)
3 steps (0 passed)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that seemed to be the problem. always the little things that are easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

it can happen if your .feature file is invalid somehow.  I once had it happen just because I had two || together in the examples table of my Scenario Outline